# Linux and/or GOW compatible - replacing a keyword with a text file

Tags: linux, shell, command-line, text-files, keyword

There's numerous examples on stackoverflow for replacing an *old keyword* with a *new keyword* using **sed**, **grep**, etc. which is an excellent method for replacing one keyword with another.

**There's a huge amount of text I wish to replace in a location in an HTML file...** What I need is a method to replace a *keyword* in the HTML file in question with all the text contained in a separate *text file* in the same directory.

*Example index.html file:*

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <meta name="description" content="desc">
    <meta name="author" content="author">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/stylesheet.css">
</head>

<body>
    <!-- bodyfile.txt -->
</body>
</html>
```

*bodyfile.txt in same directory:*

```
<P>Hello world!
```

What I wish to do is replace the *HTML Comment* with the contents of *bodyfile.txt*.

**This simplistic example can handled with keyword replacement**, however, my project will require large strings of data contained in text files and processed with scripts.  Is this sort of concatenation possible with linux or GOW?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do what you want like this:

```
sed '/<!-- bodyfile.txt -->/ {
  r bodyfile.txt
  d
}' index.html
```

When the line matches the pattern, the contents of the file `bodyfile.txt` are inserted and the pattern space (the line that has just been read) is deleted.